# Rails with Ajax. Getting data from a model to show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am just starting out with Rails and Ajax and I am facing some problems integrating Ajax and Jquery.

I have data which I want to display and update in my div using jQuery.
I have written in Jquery  a table where I can drag and drag items.
Right now I am using default items. I want to retrieve this items with back end rails but I am not too sure about how I could do it.

This is the model. I want to show these in the table.

```
class SlotAllocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :group_index, :lesson_type, :timeslot_id

  def as_json(options={}) 
  {
     :group_index =>self.group_index
     :lesson_type =>self.lesson_type
     :timeslot_id =>self.timeslot_id
  }
end
```

This is the controller actions. I've added format.js to the index and update functions.

```
  def index
    @slot_allocations = SlotAllocation.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @slot_allocations }
      format.js{ render :json => @slot_allocations }
    end
  end

    def update
    @slot_allocation = SlotAllocation.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @slot_allocation.update_attributes(params[:slot_allocation])
        format.html { redirect_to @slot_allocation, notice: 'Slot allocation was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js { head :ok}
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @slot_allocation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js  { render :js => @slot_allocation.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

In the view I have a table. It is working according to some default values I have placed in.

```
<table id='subjects' border="1">
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Now I want to change these default values to the values I have in rails.

By trying to piece together certain info I got from codes from github.
I tried out this.

```
slots= {
    url: '/slot_allocations'
}
```

To aid in my understanding I did something like that in JQuery just to see what information I could retrieve and it turns out that I get [object Object].

```
TryDiv(slots);

 function TryDiv(slots){
        var div = document.getElementById('tryout');
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + slots;
 }
```

I am not too sure what is contained in that object and would appreciate it if someone could help me out on how I could retrieve the information I need from the model.
Any articles or code samples I could refer to would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Hi. Not too sure if this is the right way but I managed to retrieve the information with getJson. Basically I create an array to store the items. var items=new Array(); And this is followed by getJson method which pushes my item into the array.  $.getJSON('slot_allocations', function(data) { $.each(data, function(i, item) { items.push(item); }); });